# Marginaleffects predictions produce different standard errors after fixed effects model compared to stata

Tags: r, stata, fixest, r-marginaleffects

I wanted to reproduce a stata code with R using `feols` from the `fixest` package and predictions from the `marginaleffects` package. However, while I manage to produce the same coefficients and standard errors using feols compared to Stata's `xtreg`, predictions calculates larger standard errors than margins in stata.

I calculate the following in stata:

```
. xtreg happy i.marry c.yrsmarried age loghhinc, fe vce(cluster pid)

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |               Robust
       happy | Coefficient  std. err.      t    P>|t|     [95% conf. interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
     1.marry |   .1450998   .0170226     8.52   0.000     .1117346     .178465
  yrsmarried |  -.0178269   .0027528    -6.48   0.000    -.0232225   -.0124314
         age |  -.0190082   .0014402   -13.20   0.000     -.021831   -.0161854
    loghhinc |   .2448844    .011323    21.63   0.000     .2226908    .2670781
       _cons |   5.921477   .0907651    65.24   0.000     5.743572    6.099381
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
     sigma_u |  1.2766298
     sigma_e |  1.2949898
         rho |  .49286093   (fraction of variance due to u_i)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. 
. margins, at(marry=(0 1) yrsmarried=(0 5 10))

Predictive margins                                     Number of obs = 210,287
Model VCE: Robust

Expression: Linear prediction, predict()
1._at: marry      =  0
       yrsmarried =  0
2._at: marry      =  0
       yrsmarried =  5
3._at: marry      =  0
       yrsmarried = 10
4._at: marry      =  1
       yrsmarried =  0
5._at: marry      =  1
       yrsmarried =  5
6._at: marry      =  1
       yrsmarried = 10

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |            Delta-method
             |     Margin   std. err.      z    P>|z|     [95% conf. interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
         _at |
          1  |   7.213823   .0053026  1360.43   0.000      7.20343    7.224216
          2  |   7.124688   .0109761   649.11   0.000     7.103176    7.146201
          3  |   7.035554   .0243252   289.23   0.000     6.987877     7.08323
          4  |   7.358923   .0141712   519.29   0.000     7.331148    7.386698
          5  |   7.269788   .0151294   480.51   0.000     7.240135    7.299441
          6  |   7.180654   .0252162   284.76   0.000     7.131231    7.230076
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And here the R results

```
> FE_CI1 <-feols(happy ~ marry + yrsmarried + loghhinc + age | pid, data = base_ego_c_r_a)
> FE_CI1
OLS estimation, Dep. Var.: happy
Observations: 210,287 
Fixed-effects: pid: 26,574
Standard-errors: Clustered (pid) 
            Estimate Std. Error   t value   Pr(>|t|)    
marry       0.145100   0.017023   8.52394  < 2.2e-16 ***
yrsmarried -0.017827   0.002753  -6.47605 9.5801e-11 ***
loghhinc    0.244884   0.011323  21.62719  < 2.2e-16 ***
age        -0.019008   0.001440 -13.19869  < 2.2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
RMSE: 1.21039     Adj. R2: 0.422222
                Within R2: 0.009788
> 
> predictions(FE_CI1, 
+             by = c("marry","yrsmarried"),
+             newdata=datagridcf(yrsmarried = c(0,5,10), marry = c(0,1))
+ )

 yrsmarried marry Estimate Std. Error    z Pr(>|z|)   S 2.5 % 97.5 %
          0     0     7.21     0.0929 77.7   <0.001 Inf  7.03   7.40
          5     0     7.12     0.0884 80.6   <0.001 Inf  6.95   7.30
         10     0     7.04     0.0858 82.0   <0.001 Inf  6.87   7.20
          0     1     7.36     0.0917 80.2   <0.001 Inf  7.18   7.54
          5     1     7.27     0.0868 83.7   <0.001 Inf  7.10   7.44
         10     1     7.18     0.0839 85.6   <0.001 Inf  7.02   7.35
```

The results in R and Stata are the same if I calculate a simple OLS model with lm in R. Hence, I expect that is the combination of feols and predictions that creates these differences.

----------------------------(added example to reproduce the results)

```
#load example panel data: here the example dataset from panelr is used
#install.packages("panelr")
data("WageData", package="panelr")

#save data for stata use
#write_dta(data=WageData, path="WageData.dta")


library("tidyverse")
library("fixest")
library("haven")
library("marginaleffects")

FE_CI1<-feols(lwage ~ union + ms + occ + ed + exp | id, data = WageData, panel.id = ~id)

predictions(FE_CI1, 
            by = c("ms","exp"),
            newdata=datagridcf(exp = c(0,10,20), ms = c(0,1)),
            vcov = ~id
)

 exp ms Estimate Std. Error   z Pr(>|z|)   S 2.5 % 97.5 %
   0  0     4.78     0.0143 335   <0.001 Inf  4.75   4.81
  10  0     5.75     0.0213 269   <0.001 Inf  5.71   5.79
  20  0     6.72     0.0364 184   <0.001 Inf  6.65   6.79
   0  1     4.75     0.0320 149   <0.001 Inf  4.69   4.81
  10  1     5.72     0.0352 162   <0.001 Inf  5.65   5.79
  20  1     6.68     0.0456 147   <0.001 Inf  6.60   6.77
```

```
use "WageData.dta"
xtreg lwage i.union i.ms i.occ c.ed c.exp , fe vce(cluster id)

margins, at(ms=(0 1) exp=(0 10 20)) 

Predictive margins                                       Number of obs = 4,165
Model VCE: Robust

Expression: Linear prediction, predict()
1._at: ms  =  0
       exp =  0
2._at: ms  =  0
       exp = 10
3._at: ms  =  0
       exp = 20
4._at: ms  =  1
       exp =  0
5._at: ms  =  1
       exp = 10
6._at: ms  =  1
       exp = 20

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |            Delta-method
             |     Margin   std. err.      z    P>|z|     [95% conf. interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
         _at |
          1  |   4.782331   .0405666   117.89   0.000     4.702821     4.86184
          2  |   5.749547   .0273942   209.88   0.000     5.695855    5.803239
          3  |   6.716763    .021801   308.09   0.000     6.674034    6.759492
          4  |   4.750068   .0354733   133.91   0.000     4.680542    4.819595
          5  |   5.717285   .0182065   314.03   0.000     5.681601    5.752969
          6  |   6.684501   .0049639  1346.62   0.000     6.674772     6.69423
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: In Stata, it looks like you are using robust standard errors for the marginal predictions, but *not* the same cluster-robust standard errors as in R. If I were you, my first diagnostic step would be to add a similar `vce()` option after your `margins` call.

Comment: Hi @Vincent first of all thank you for the marginaleffects package. I tested that again and there is no conventional `vce()` for margins in Stata. It seems that it simply uses the cluster-robust standard errors specifed in the `xtreg` call. If I do not specify vce(cluster pid) in the `xtreg` call the standard errors in the predictions after `margins` are even smaller.

Comment: I think I cam closer to the problem. If I use predictions after `feols` it does not produce a warning or an error. However, if I again specify `vce(~pid)` within the predictions call after `feols` i get the following message: "Unable to extract a variance-covariance matrix using this `vcov` argument. Standard errors are computed using the default variance instead.." The standard errors remain the same as if I would not specify `vce(~pid)`.After an `lm` function with cluster-robust standard errors in the predictions call I do not get the message and the standard errors are the same as in STATA.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have access to Stata right now so I can't help diagnose more. The only other thing I'd say is that when you specify the `vcov` argument **inside the `feols()` call**, then the variance-covariance stored inside the model object is whatever you picked (not IID). So in principle, if you specify the covariance you want using fixest, you shouldn't have to use `marginaleffects`'s `vcov` argument at all, because we're already using the fixest ones.

Comment: totally get that and if I manually specify again in the `feols` call `vcov(~id)` I get the same standard errors in R as one would expect. I also tested again if predictions after an `feols` model without fixed effects and clustered standard errors produces the same results as in stata and it does. Thus, it is either that stata's `margins` behaves differently with `xtreg` than with `reg` or that predictions works differently depending whether `feols` includes a fixed effect or not.